# Has no property in common gRPC typescript

Tags: typescript, server, grpc

hi i'm new with typescript, i want to make a grpc server with typescript. But i have trouble with how my server.ts work. My GetAllNews service said

> has no properties in common with type 'NewsList'

and i can't push into an array in my AddNews the message is

> Argument of type '{ id: string; title?: string; body?: string; postImage?: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string; title: string; body: string; postImage: string; }'.
> Property 'title' is optional in type '{ id: string; title?: string; body?: string; postImage?: string; }' but required in type '{ id: string; title: string; body: string; postImage: string; }'

and my EditNews service show an error

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

this is how i setup my server.ts . where do i do wrong?

```
import path from 'path'
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js'
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { ProtoGrpcType } from './proto/news';
import { NewsServiceHandlers } from './proto/newsPackage/NewsService';

const PORT = 9999;
const PROTO_FILE = './proto/random.proto'

const packageDef = protoLoader.loadSync(path.resolve(__dirname, PROTO_FILE))
const grpcObj = (grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDef) as unknown) as ProtoGrpcType
const newsPackage = grpcObj.newsPackage
let newsLists = [
    { id: "1", title: "Note 1", body: "Content 1", postImage: "Post image 1" },
    { id: "2", title: "Note 2", body: "Content 2", postImage: "Post image 2" },
]

function main() {
    const server = getServer()
    server.bindAsync(`0.0.0.0:${PORT}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    (err, port) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
        console.log('Your server is started on port', port)
        server.start()
    })
}

function getServer() {
    const server = new grpc.Server()
    server.addService(newsPackage.NewsService.service, {
        "GetAllNews": (_, callback) => {
            callback(null, newsLists)
        },
        "GetNews": (call, callback) => {
            const newsId = call.request.id
            const newsItem = newsLists.find(({ id }) => id !== newsId)
            callback(null, newsItem)
        },
        "AddNews": (call, callback) => {
            let news = { id: uuidv4(), ...call.request}
            newsLists.push(news)
            callback(null, news)
        }, 
        "EditNews": (call, callback) => {
            const newsId = call.request.id
            const newsItem = newsLists.find(({ id }) => newsId == id)
            newsItem.body = call.request.body
            newsItem.postImage = call.request.postImage
            newsItem.title = call.request.title
            callback(null, newsItem)
        },
        "DeleteNews": (call, callback) => {
            const newsId = call.request.id;
            newsLists = newsLists.filter(({ id }) => id !== newsId);
            callback(null, {});
        }
    } as NewsServiceHandlers)
    return server
}

main()
```

and this is my proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package newsPackage;

message News {
    string id = 1;
    string title = 2;
    string body = 3;
    string postImage = 4;
}

service NewsService {
    rpc GetAllNews (Empty) returns (NewsList) {}
    rpc GetNews (NewsId) returns (News) {}
    rpc DeleteNews (NewsId) returns (Empty) {}
    rpc EditNews (News) returns (News) {}
    rpc AddNews (News) returns (News) {}
}

message NewsId {
    string id = 1;
}

message Empty {}

message NewsList {
   repeated News news = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `GetAllNews` implementation is that your `NewsList` message definition is a message containing a repeated field named `news` of `News` messages, so the object that you pass should reflect that. In your code, you are passing a bare array of objects, but you should instead pass an object with a `news` field that points to that array.

The problem with your `AddNews` implementation is that objects that come from gRPC may have some fields omitted if those fields are set to the default value, but your `newsLists` variable has the inferred type `{ id: string; title: string; body: string; postImage: string; }[]`, which requires every field to be set in each item. You can solve this by setting the `defaults` option in `protoLoader.loadSync` or by explicitly declaring a type for `newsLists` that allows for unset fields.

The problem with `EditNews` seems to be a similar incompatibility as with `AddNews`, and the same solution should fix it.